# Why can java.lang.Object no be coverted into T?

Tags: java, generics

I am making a genaric linked list and I ran into this error

```
incompatible types: java.lang.object cannot be converted into T
```

I don't understand, because getData and data are in therms of T.

```
// accessor and mutator for the data component
    public T getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

This is the code where the error comes from:

```
// copy constructor
    // clones the list l and sets the last element as the current
    public List(List l)
    {
        Node n = l.head;
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.curr = null;
        this.num_items = 0;

        while(n!= null)
        {
            this.InsertAfter(n.getData());
            n = n.getLink();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your class also parameterized with <T>?  The list needs to be parameterized too.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to write and use [generic methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) in Java.  Please show us compilable  code, and the exact error message.

Comment: @AdrianM. yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List(List l)
```

should probably read

```
public List(List<T> l)
```

The compiler should give you a *raw types* warning. (So long as you have lint enabled. Do enable lint.)

Or possibly, the more general, but less readable:

```
public List(List<? extends T> l)
```